# What architectures and bootloaders for tablets is needed to run the Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: intel, tablet, compatibility, arm

Lately you can see all kinds of laptop/tablet/pc hybrids: Laptop convertibles, Tablet PCs, Tablets. Also, they run either ARM, Atom or full Core i3/5/7 processors. Some use GRUB, others use EUFI.

I was wondering on which of these can I install *Ubuntu Desktop edition* (currently 14.04 LTS). I'd like to be able to:

1. Boot up from the USB drive (probably some keyboard shortcut)
2. Install Ubuntu with the regular image
3. Touch support
4. Optionally recognize tablet keys and orientation

I'd like to know which architectures (Core/Atom/ARM) and bootloaders (GRUB/EUFI) supported Ubuntu Desktop.
Can I install Ubuntu Desktop on any tablet, as long as it runs Core i3/5/7, for eg.?

Thanks